# Tibco RV C client stops receiving messages

Tags: c, tibco

I've got a C client listening to Tibco RV (using 8.4.0). The source pumps out messages on PREFIX1.* and PREFIX2.* pretty frequently (can be several times per second).

I have six threads, each listening to a particular SUFFIX, eg PREFIX1.SUFFIX_A and PREFIX2.SUFFIX_A. So each thread has a listener and its own queue for these two messages. I've got a queue size limit of 1000, dropping the oldest 200 if we hit that (but never have more than about 40 in the queue at busy times).

After running fine for many hours, each day the program suddenly stops receiving data. The source continues to publish but I no longer dispatch events from any queue. I don't understand what can have caused this (aside from deleting the listeners).

What might have caused the listening to stop? Or alternatively, given the system is high frequency how can this be investigated? Can I tell whether a listener is still active via the C interface? I couldn't see anything in the API for that.

Thanks for any help,
-Dave

Comment: Intermittent, rare bugs in multi-threaded programs is almost always caused by race conditions. So that's where you should stop searching: check all variables shared between multiple threads.

Comment: There's very little shared state between the threads. There may be a lot more going on inside the tibrv dll but I have no visibility into that of course. I was wondering if this might be a known possible state for RV to get into.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was that the machine had only a partial install of RV. In particular, there was no rv daemon in the package that we had for that machine. I'm actually a bit confused how we managed to get network data at all after re-reading the docs but it seems that without a daemon we can achieve networking until a minor network problem, then nothing; with the daemon we recover from network errors.

So the fix for this case was simply to install the full package and ensure the daemon runs constantly. Now the problem appears to have disappeared.